# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5+4n-1}{3^{2n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I have troubles finding the limit of the following series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5+4n-1}{3^{2n+1}}$

So far I figured it'd easier to split the sum into:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5}{3^{2n+1}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n-1}{3^{2n+1}}$

= $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 5 \cdot\frac{1}{3^{2n+1}} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4n-1 \cdot \frac{1}{3^{2n+1}}$

And with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{w^n} = \frac{1}{w-1}$ you get the following terms:

$5\cdot \frac{1}{3^{2n+1}-1} + 4n-1\cdot \frac{1}{3^{2n+1}-1}$

which is bascially a sequence, but im stuck right here.. help is very appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you write that $5+4n-1$ as simply $4+4n$? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depend on the geometric series , we can get the following to compute the sum
$${\frac {x^2}{1-x^2}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }x^{2n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!$$

$${\displaystyle {\frac {x^2}{(1-x^2)^{2}}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{2n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. We have that for $|x|<1$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}\quad\mbox{and}\quad \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5+4n-1}{3^{2n+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4+4n}{3\cdot 9^{n}}=\frac{4}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1/9)^{n}+\frac{4}{27}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1/9)^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let  $F_m=\dfrac{Am+B}{3^{2m+1}}$ and
 $\dfrac{4+4n}{3^{2n+1}}=F_{n-1}-F_n$

$\implies\dfrac{4+4n}{3^{2n+1}}=\dfrac{A(n-1)+B}{3^{2n-1}}-\dfrac{An+B}{3^{2n+1}}=\dfrac{9\{A(n-1)+B\}-(An+B)}{3^{2n+1}}$

$\implies4+4n=8B-9A+8An$

$\implies8A=4\iff A=\dfrac12,4=8B-9A\iff B=?$

Clearly, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{4+4n}{3^{2n+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(F_{n-1}-F_n\right)=F_0-\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n$$

Now can you establish  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n=0$$